# Docker on WSL2 and Ubuntu not pushing images

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I've installed Docker on WSL2 and Ubuntu and I'm not able to push any image to any registry. The process seems to start but then hangs up indefinitely without any error message.

[image]

Everything else works flawlessly, I can build and pull images and run containers but I cannot push anything. I've been trying private and public registries with no success. Daemon logs don't show anything meaningful, they just hang up.

Not sure if this might be related but I've been using Docker Desktop (with WSL2) previously without any problem. I completely uninstalled Docker Desktop and WSL2 and did a fresh install of WSL2, Ubuntu + Docker.

Here's the pertinent section of daemon logs:

[image]

I'm quite lost here so I'd really appreciate any suggestion on how to effectively debug this issue.

Comment: Can you try pushing a very small image? Like pushing an `alpine` image to your user repository?

Comment: Pushing an `alpine` image gave the same issue, but pushing `hello-world` worked indeed. So the issue might be related to image's size? Any idea?